# Moving the mouse pointer to the cursor

Tags: autohotkey

Is there an autohotkey function which brings the mouse pointer to the active cursor?

(assume that the active window has a active cursor, e.g., in notepad, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MouseMove, A_CaretX, A_CaretY, 0
```

**A_CaretX** and **A_CaretY**  are the  current X and Y coordinates of the **caret** (text insertion point). The coordinates are relative to the active window unless CoordMode is used to make them relative to the entire screen. If there is no active window or the caret position cannot be determined, these variables are blank.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#misc